# Как перебрать коллекцию и просумировать второй индекс всех обьектов коллекции?

Tags: java

я б перебрал простым циклом for но не получаеться так как первый индекс обьекта типа String, а нужно получить сумму например всех вторых индексов(1000+550+900). Возможно ли такое, возможно можно указать в цикле чтобы прорабатывались только данные инт или пропускались стриги? Или проще сделать новые дополнительные обэкты без стринга? Но не хотелось бы создавать лишний код.

```
    SemiPrecious opal = new SemiPrecious("Opal", 1000, 3, 1);
    Precious ruby = new Precious("Ruby", 550, 4, 2);
    Precious almaz = new Precious("Almaz", 900, 3, 1);

    List<Jawelry> stones = new ArrayList<>();
    stones.add(almaz);
    stones.add(ruby);
    stones.add(opal);
```

Answer (score 1):

У объектов нет индексов. Есть поля. Данные объекта. Чтобы получить значение конкретного поля существует метод, называемый геттером. 
Допустим классы SemiPrecious и Precious имеет поля:

```
String name; 
int aaa;
int bbb; 
int ccc;
```

и геттеры:

```
getName();
getAaa();
getBbb();
getCcc();
```

Тогда цикл суммирования данных "ааа" всех объектов, входящих в коллекцию stones будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stones.size(); i++) {
    sum = sum + stones.get(i).getAaa();
}
```

Конечно, это очень грубо. Как выглядят поля и геттеры в ваших классах никому здесь неизвестно. 
Если выложите код, то можно будет написать более точно.

Answer (score 1):

Функционалка лучше...

int sum = stones.stream().mapToInt(Jawelry::getIndex).sum();

Comment: .....это магия!

Comment: @СергійІваницький нет, просто функционалка, она может))